# Change symbols of levels of unordered list using outlines

Tags: lists, nesting

Is it possible to change this latex from outlines package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}
 \1 Level 1
   \2 Level 2
     \3 Level 3
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

so that it looks like the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the makers document-wise, you can redefine them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\blacksquare$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\star$}

\begin{document}
    \begin{outline}
        \1 Level 1
        \2 Level 2
        \3 Level 3
        \4 Level 4
    \end{outline}
\end{document}
```

[image]